# MQL4 - one order per day

Tags: mql4

I would like to write out a boolean that returns `false` if the last order (`close`) has been performed less than 24 hours earlier.

I tried with this code, but it always returns `false`:

```
bool OnePerDay()
{
     if (  OrderSelect( 1, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY ) )
     {     

           if (  OrderOpenTime() <  24*60*60 ) return( true );
     }
     return( false );
}
```

My goal is to perform at least one trade per day (or other time interval), so it should open a position and close it, but not perform other orders in less than 24 hours after.

Comment: I know it is legal since compilation does not return errors.
It does not have to return false at every order, but only when the order is performed less than 24 hours.
I'm not shure that in this way he keep the correct order i.e. the last order performed by the tester

Comment: I voted +1 in most of the answer (more or less all of yours), but under 15 reputation this votes are not displayed.
With this question (my 4th) I reached 15 reputation, and now i can +1 in all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to write out the bool function, please read comment for the definitions.

The solution is in the correct enumeration of the closed order in the for cycle for the order select, so this boolean return true only when the last close order is performed in more than 24 hours before.

```
int orhito () { return OrdersHistoryTotal(); } // number of closed  orders
int orto () {   return OrdersTotal();        } // number of pending orders

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool onePerTime() { /* boolean that should return true
                               if the last close order
                               was performed more than 24 hours before */

     if (  orhito() == 0 ) return ( true );
     else{
           for ( int i = orhito(); i >= 0 ; i-- ) { 
                 if (  OrderSelect( i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY ) ) { 
                       if (  TimeCurrent() - OrderCloseTime()  < 24*60*60 )
                             return( false );
                 } 
           }
           return( true );
     }
}
```

Comment: **This approach is principally wrong**. Given one trade was XTO'd today morning, and still left not XTO-terminated, the conditions in the above proposed implementation will return such case as True, while the still active trade was active within the last 24-hrs.

Comment: I use this approach with 3 pips of TP and 3 of SL.
The EA where I use it is intended for the sole purpose of detecting some precise situations and labeling them with a trade.
I did not know a better way to make such an "exploration" in the charts

Comment: why your way is bad: if you do not have any trades in history - ok you get `TRUE`. then you do not check any trades in history (even if they closed a second ago) but loops over open trades, and if trade is open, its `OrderCloseTime()` is 0, and `TimeCurrent()-0<24*60*60 is false` (no action).so you do not even check if open trades were open less then 24h ago. if you close a deal and try to open another after a second - this function gives `TRUE` that is incorrect. I do not see a case where your function returns `FALSE`.

Comment: I will investigate more deeply about yours issues, but for now I open only one  operation per day when conditions in the BUY_H1 are satisfacted. 
Until yesterday, when it found the required conditions it opened more than 300 positions in a few hours (and close them immediately, there is a take profit= stoploss= 5 pips)

Comment: @DanielKniaz  `OrdersHistoryTotal()` counts the number of closed orders,  `MODE_HISTORY` make selecting orders from history pool (closed and canceled order).
Please keep in mind that in this EA I work with the sole purpose of detecting some precise situations and labeling them with a trade, so I setted stoplos and take profit in few pips, and positions are open a few minutes.
I see that, where he first opened 300 trades in few hours, now it opens at most 1 trade per day...if you want to try yourself I send you the entire EA, so much is not a secret

Comment: sorry didnt notice that, i thought it was `MODE_TRADES`. then: 1. you check that a trade was closed not opened less then 24h ago; 2. you do not check current trades

Comment: exactly, but notice that with stoploss/takeprofit at 3 pips every trades remain open less than 5 minutes, and the condition are posed on H4 bars, with max open order = 1, so it must be solid.
This is a code for the study purpose only.
By the way MQL4 has not pattern characterization instruments, did not you ever do it, or you know some references?

Answer (score 1):

`OrderOpenTime()` is a `datetime` variable, which means it is integer larger then zero and smaller then `2^31-1` representing number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970. E.g., it is 9:20:07 am UTC 14 Oct 2017, which is 1507972807 in `datetime` format. if you want to check that the trade is open today or earlier, you need to know start of today's date, e.g. `iTime(_Symbol(),PERIOD_D1,0)` or `TimeCurrent()/(24*60*60)*(24*60*60)` which is 1507939200. If you need to check that trade lasts less then 24 hours - either `TimeCurrent()-OrderOpenTime()` to compare with 24*60*60 or get expected time when it should return true and compare with that date. Additionally you need to think of cases when order is open on Friday and now it is Monday (so more then 24 hours but is it ok for your task?)

altogether:

```
const int DAY_SECONDS = 24*60*60;
bool isTradeOpenToday(int ticket){//true means trade lasts less then 24h
   datetime now = TimeCurrent();
   datetime now_minus_24h = now - DAY_SECONDS;
   if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET)){
      return now_minus_24h - OrderOpenTime() < 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: I've modified `if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET))` in `if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET,MODE_HISTORY))return(true);` because I want a bool function that returns true when the last close order is performed more than 24 hours before.
It should work.
I only don't know how this order is labeled in tikets. 
`isTradeOpenToday(1)` this is referred to the last order performed? This way doesen't works.

My goal is to perform at least one trade per day, so it should open order and close it, but not perform other order in less than 24 hours after.

Comment: you may check tickets in history from the end (OrdersHistoryTotal()-1) to 0 and break after you see an order was opened earlier(all orders of different symbols and magics will be there so need to pick up the one you need (if it exists) and check its time. alternative way is to have a global variable of time of last open deal, when opening new trade - reassign new datetime to that variable, when entering - check TimeCurrent() vs that variable

Comment: This way doesn't works 
`const int DAY_SECONDS = 24*60*60;   datetime now = TimeCurrent();
   datetime now_minus_24h = now - DAY_SECONDS;
int hstTotal=OrdersHistoryTotal();

bool onePerTime() {
  for(int i=0;i<hstTotal;i++)
    {
    
     if(OrderSelect(hstTotal,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)) ;
       {
        if (now_minus_24h - OrderOpenTime() < 0) ;
       }
       return false;
       
    }
    return true;
}`

Comment: if you have 1 trade in history, hstTotal will be 1 but you can select from 0 to n-1 (to zero). so OrderSelect (i,SELECT_*) instead of selecting unavailable trade

Comment: Oh sorry, now I corrected.
anyway it doesn't work, it seems that the tester does not recognize the SelectOrder command.
As a test i defined `datetime dur() 
{ for(int i=0;i<hstTotal;i++) { 
     if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)) ;}
return (TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime());}` and i print it in corner info `text[3]= "Duration: " +  TimeToStr(  dur() , TIME_MINUTES  );`
the output shows that also when there are yet no order opened it start to count order duration...

Comment: I fixed the output of the open order duration adding `return true; ` after OrderSelect 
`datetime dur() { for(int i=0;i<hstTotal;i++) { if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)) return(true);} return (TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime());}`
Now it shows correctly the duration of the orders in the print.

The same code does not work to define the time passed since the last order `datetime clus () { for(int i=0;i<hstTotal;i++) { 
     if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)) return(true);}
return (TimeCurrent() - OrderCloseTime());} ` I can't explain why

Comment: i cant understand what the problem is and what you have

Comment: I would like to open at most one trade per day, and it makes about 300...
I have not yet understood why OrderSelect is substantially ignored when select closed orders

Comment: from the comment i can see that after any OrderSelect() function returns true, which is incorrect

Comment: if i wrote `datetime clus ()
         { 
              for ( int i=0;i<orhito;i++) 
              { 
                  if ( OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY) == TRUE ) return (TimeCurrent() - OrderCloseTime());  
              }
              
         }`

returns error

Comment: what error? it doesnt understand `orhito`? and why you ask us about that, if you can read the error description and understand that you need to declare 'int orhito=OrdersHitoryTotal();` and then compile again?

Comment: never said that it doesn't understand `orhito`, it is already defined in this way and works perfectly.
The error comes when i remove `return true` after `OrderSelect`.
And i don't understand why

Comment: `')' - not all control paths return a value` - this means that in some cases (e.g., if orhito<=0 or if it cannot select any ticket) it does not know what to return. so the last line before final `}` needs to return default value, e.g. `return EMPTY_VALUE;` or -1 or something else (depending on what you need, keep in mind that for open deals `OrderCloseTime()` returns zero

Comment: Ok this have fixed the problem, in union with the correct enumeration in the for cycle for the boolean function that turn true when the last close is performed more than 24 houres before.
I correct in my answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

### How to scan the `db.POOL`?

```
#define aTimeLAST iTime( _Symbol, PERIOD_H1, 23 )  // 24 H1 Bars back at Market
     // aTimeLAST  Time() - 24*60*60               // 24 hours since this Bar

void OnTick(){

     if   WasNoTradeWithinLAST( aTimeLAST ) {
          ...
     }
}

bool WasNoTradeWithinLAST( const datetime aClosestAllowedTIME ) {

     for (  int anOrdinalNUM  = 0;
                anOrdinalNUM <  OrdersTotal();
                anOrdinalNUM++
                ) {
            if ( !OrderSelect( anOrdinalNUM; SELECT_BY_POS; MODE_HISTORY ){
                  PrintFormat( "OrderSelect( %d ) failed. Will continue.", anOrdinalNUM );
            }
            else {

                  if (  OrderCloseTime() >= aClosestAllowedTIME
                     || OrderOpenTime()  >= aClosestAllowedTIME
                        )
                        return( false ); // WELL, XTO WAS WITHIN LAST 24HRS
            }
     }
     return( true );  // NONE XTO HAS BEEN PERFORMED DURING LAST 24HRS
 }
```

Comment: I've correcter syntax error that were displayed, implemented this code in a boolean function , but it doesn't works.
My goal is to perform at least one trade per day (or other time interval), so it should open a position and close it, but not perform other orders in less than 24 hours after.
So I need a boolean function (or at least boolean variable) that i can call in the open order section that returns true only if the last trade (open + close) was performed more than 24 (or x ) hours before.